# Trouble with understanding objects ( Getting the age difference between mother and child nodes)

Tags: javascript

I am currently going through a bunch of the old exercises in my book, and am having a bit of trouble understand the key concepts of objects, so here is my question. Consider the following JSON code

```
var ANCESTRY_FILE = "[\n  " + [
  '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',
  '{"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"}',
  '{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}'
```

The problem statement was basically to get the average of the difference between mothers and children. Below is the answer

```
var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});

var differences = ancestry.filter(function(person) {
  return byName[person.mother] != null;
}).map(function(person) {
  return person.born - byName[person.mother].born;
});

console.log(average(differences));
```

I think I understand the code, however I am a bit confused as to why some things are happening the way they are. First of all `byName[person.name] = person;` is making the `byName` object have a key of `name` and setting it to that original object. So basically one could think of it as on one iteration

```
Carolus Haverbeke: '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}'
```

Now my confusion is. How come if I try to `console.log(obj[person.mother])`, I get a bunch of undefined values, but sometimes I get an object? Shouldn't everything be `undefined`?  We never set `obj[person.mother]` to anything.

Secondly, why can't `byName[person.mother] != null;` be replaced with `person.mother !=null`? Don't we want to filter based on `nulls`? I can't tell what the difference is here between those two checks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set a working example, because yours was throwing a lot of errors, check this snippet:
https://repl.it/Cidr

Now, to answer your questions:

> How come if I try to console.log(obj[person.mother]), I get a bunch of undefined values, but sometimes I get an object? Shouldn't everything be undefined? We never set obj[person.mother] to anything.

I guess by obj you actually mean byName(which is a dictionary).
With this asumption, you're storing all of the data in this dictionary.
The reason why sometimes you get undefined and others don't, is because some folks have mothers which ain't in the list, check this example file:

```
var ANCESTRY_FILE = "[\n  " + [
  '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',
  '{"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"}',
  '{"name": "Sophia van Damme", "sex": "f", "born": 1851, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Someone"}',
  '{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}'
  ] + " ]";
```

Emma de Milliano is the daughter of Sophia van Damme, and Sophia is in the list (she was born in 1851), but Carolus Haverbeke is the son of Maria van Brussel, but Maria is not in the list (we don't know anything about her), so, if you try to find Maria in the dictionary (byName) you won't find anything.

> Why can't byName[person.mother] != null; be replaced with person.mother !=null? Don't we want to filter based on nulls? I can't tell what the difference is here between those two checks.

This question is also related to the previous question. Let's keep on mind the same example file.

If you try to find in the dictionary (byName) the name of someone who is not in the example file it will return undefined actually, not null, because the dictionary doesn't have a defined value for that name (it doesn't exist).
So, if you do `person.mother` you will get just the name of that person's mother.
But if you do `byName(person.mother)` you're not asking about the mother's name (a string), you're asking about the person (name, sex, born, died, father, mother) which is actually an object, not a string.

I hope the snippet help you out, play with the file adding and removing persons (especially the mothers) and you'll notice right away what's happening.

Comment: Oh, we do byName[person.mother] and not person.mother,because .map will not work on a string right?

Comment: No, the reason the validation is `byName[person.mother] != undefined` and not `person.mother != undefined` is because you need to compare the age of a son/daughter with the age of his/her mother, what the validation is doing is filtering the persons so you can't compare a son if his mother is not in the dictionary (byName).

Comment: What happens if we do person.mother!= undefined? What is that implying?

Comment: By the way I gave sample data, Here is the whole JSON http://jsfiddle.net/99CL3/222/, is what you say still true?

Comment: If you do `person.mother != undefined` you're just asking if there's a person (anybody) in the file whose mother doesn't have the name property.

**Your link is wrong.**

Comment: But isn't that what we want to do? We first just want to filter our ANYONE without a mother. See here sorry http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/ancestry.js

Comment: Ok, I can finally get what do you mean.
Still, that's not what you want to filter, see this case:
`'{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}'`
Maria de Rycke has a mother, isn't it?
Well, indeed she has one, but her mother is not in the list.
Summarizing, the fact that your mother's name is not null, it doesn't mean that she is in the list, and we need her to be in the list to extract the properties like `born`.

Comment: AHHHH, makes sense. So how does "byName[person.mother] !" fix this issue?

Comment: As you already notice, `byName` is a dictionary where the `key` is the _name of the person_ and the `value` is the _person object_ with all their data.
You iterate over the array which holds all the _persons_, what you're asking in the loop (the filter is looping through the `ancestry` var) is if you have the data of a mother for a person, if you do then there's someone (she does exists) with her name in the dictionary (`"byName[person.mother] != undefined`) then you compare their dates of birth, otherwise you know you don't have the mother date of `birth`, so you just skip it.

Comment: ohh, I see I get it. This truly is confusing if you don't understand the basics of objects. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing at the beginning, glad to be helpful. Keep on learning!

Answer (score 1):

Does this explain things a bit more:

```js
var obj = {};

var parent = { 
  name: 'The Parents Name',
  parent: null
}


var child = { 
  name: 'The childs name',
  parent: 'The Parents Name'
}

obj[parent.name] = parent;
obj[child.name] = child;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

When you refer to an objects attribute with `[]` you are referring to the name on the attribute, not the value. ie:

```js
var obj = { key: 'value' };

// These two are identical
console.log(obj.key);
console.log(obj['key']);
```

This also means that `byName[person.mother]` returns the object and `person.mother` returns the name. So `byName[person.name].mother != null;` be replaced with `person.mother != null`

Comment: byName[person.mother] returns what object? it returns whatever properties in byName have a name that corresponds to a mother of something else?

Comment: For example if we console.log(byName[person.mother]) in the foreach loop why do we got tons of undefined and some objects?

Comment: Calling `console.log(byName[person.mother])` will return the object that have the same `name` set as the `mother` attribute. So you will get the mother of `person`

Comment: Why does it do that...? That seems random

Comment: You have actually come up with an elegant solution to the problem. When you run `ancestry.forEach(function(person) {  byName[person.name] = person; });` you are creating a hashed map called `byName` of people that can be looked up by name. You will have problems with this if two people have the same name though.

Comment: So why can't we do person.mother not equal to null?

Comment: If you just want to check that the mothers name is not null, then there is no reason that you can't do that, but if there is someone with a name for their mother, but there is no person person object with that name (for the mother), you will try to get the mothers age and you will get an error. But if that is not a problem, then it doesn't matter